# Bootstrap dropdown-menu not working in Liferay 6.2

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, liferay-6

I'm trying to do a new navbar in Liferay 6.2, but dropdown menu isn't working. I suspect AUI is guilty of this, but not sure here you got my code:

```
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                ....
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#demo">
                            simple collapsible
                        </button>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu child-menu" id="demo">
                            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Enlace 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Enlace 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"> Enlace 3</a></li>
                            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                            <li><button class="btn navbar-btn btn-success"> Boton</button></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
```

It's an example, I haven't started the real solution yet. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!, solved like this:

```
                    <div class="dropdown">   
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
                                simple collapsible
                            </button>

                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="demo">
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> link 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> link 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#"> link 3</a></li>
                                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                                <li><button class="btn navbar-btn btn-success"> button </button></li>
                            </ul>

                            </div>
                    </div>
```

It was needed `<div class="dropdown">` and `<button... data-target="#">`. I suppouse it's because bootstrap works in a different way with dropdown and collapse.